# Connect hair particle to emitter mesh

Tags: particles

I'm trying to create whiskers of a hairy animal, and I can't found a way to keep the whisker's hair particle close enough to the mesh.

Here is an illustration:

[image]

It's not a mesh instance, I'm using the Cycles Hair Rendering with a "curve segment" primitive and "Thick" shape.

Is there a way to get rid of the offset between hair's start and the emitter mesh?

I've tried to reduce the velocity and increase the length, but both seems to do the same, increasing offset.

Comment: Are you using a mesh? If so, extrude the bottom loop downwards well below the mesh origin.

Comment: Nope, it's a "built-in" hair particle (Thick Curve Segment of Cycles Hair Rendering) I edited my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I finally found what goes wrong. It's simply due to the particle settings: I checked "B-spline" in the "render" section, which interpolate hairs shape using B-spline, and induce a shift between the root vertice of hair and its actual rendered root.

[image]

I thought using this setting be useful to have smooth shaped hairs, but in fact using "Curve segment primitive" (Cycles Hair Rendering panel) is sufficient and works great !

[image]

Comment: You just saved my day, spent two hours on the same issue!