# Why isn't my hair connecting?

Tags: particles

This is my first time using hair particles and I've managed to figure out many of the settings, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's sitting *above* the emitter. I tried checking the B-Spline option as [a similar post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28651/connect-hair-particle-to-emitter-mesh) has as an answer, but it didn't do anything (If anything, it made the gap worse). Are there any other solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your subdivision surface is on a lower level than the particle system. You can change it in the **Modifier tab**.

Compare these two pictures:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd already applied the subsurf, so it's not that. I'm honestly stumped. I've been changing random hair settings in the hope something will work, but so far I haven't found anything relating to root height.

Comment: Maybe in the particle systems tab, 'Render' section, the Start timing has an offset?

Comment: Nope, it's 0.000